# get updated Twitter profile picture in Unity Engine C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to, in my game, link the players to my Twitter account and the account of the artist of my game. However, I don't know how to get the updated version of the profile picture of the accounts (which is what I want to include in the credits UI).

I know that I can use the `UnityWebRequest` to pick an image from a site and convert it to a sprite to use in the Image component, but every time that the Twitter user changes its profile picture the URL of the current image changes entirely.

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use Twitter's [API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object) and access the `profile_image_url_https` property of the User object.

You probably don't want to do the Twitter API authorization client-side in your Unity app, so I'd recommend doing this on some sort of minimalist server API endpoint of your own that you stand up (on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) or similar).

It would just expose some routes like `/developerTwitter` and `/artistTwitter` that will pull the relevant information from the Twitter API using credentials contained in the server's environment variables.